# Fill table from some data in another table

Tags: excel, vba, office365, excel-2019, excel-2021

I have "tblDataBase" for save request with below description.
every request can have more than one rows data.

1- 2000 Rows
2- 20 Columns
3- every row have uniqe ID in column 1
4- every request have uniqe ID in column 2 (requestID)

also have another table "tblPOD" in middle form (the form had header and footer)
in this table I have 9 columns and I wanna fill this table when I double clicking on "tblDataBase" row.
but, have to fill with requestID (same as Filter with requestID) and use some of columns as below column number:
Columns 4 , 5 , 7 , 8 , 9 , 11 , 13 , 14 , 15

i wanna creat Warehouse remittance receipt from tracker data.

thank you for your solutions

i tried filter, but need to use all columns or sided columns and when data is much, #spill error showing because i can't control rows quantity.

Comment: Please edit your question and add the code you have tried.